# Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(url) returns null when called by Delayed::Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, feedzirra

Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(url) isn't called directly. I have a FeedJob that is called by DJ. The job does a Feed.find(id_passed_into_feed_job).update_feed. The update_feed method has the call to Feedzirra. When I call update_feed from within the console, everything works as expected. When DJ makes the call, Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse returns nil.

What is the difference between the environments of console and DJ that would cause this problem?

How do I troubleshoot what is wrong with Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse?

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being with the New Relic gem. See this bug report: https://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra/issues/167

The fix is to add

```
disable_curb: true
```

to the newrelic.yml